How to break a loop in Ansible when some condition matched?
I need a method to stop looping in Ansible like break in for statement in C++ or Bash. For example, I need to the last value before the loop scan to 0.
The default/main.yml
---
os_vars:
  - 8
  - 10
  - 15
  - 6
  - 0
  - 7
  - 25

The tasks/main.yml
- name: Debug variables
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    a: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ os_vars }}"
  when: item > 0

And the output
TASK [test_role : Debug variables] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=8)
ok: [localhost] => (item=10)
ok: [localhost] => (item=15)
ok: [localhost] => (item=6)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=0)
ok: [localhost] => (item=7)
ok: [localhost] => (item=25)

I know I can set other bool variable to control the looping didn't assign a with following items, but I also need to save time to increase performance of this playbook, as sometime this looping body might be a huge array and we don't need to check the following items when some condition matched ...
Please share your comments. Thanks in advance.

Q: "I know I can set other bool variable to control the looping didn't assign a with following items"
Right, as there are
Similar Q&A

How to break loop in Ansible?
How to break with_lines cycle in Ansible?

and many more ...
Q: "I need a method to stop looping in Ansible like break in for statement in C++ or Bash."
Such is not available. You can't break out the loop, you can only implement to skip.
This is because

Things to know about programming using Ansible

Ansible is not a language:
If Ansible isn't a programming language, then what is it? Ansible is a tool written in Python, and it uses the declarative markup language YAML to describe the Desired State of devices and configuration. ... You declare aspects you want to be configured on a target device, such as that a file or directory exists, a package is installed, a service is running, and so on.


The Zen of Ansible

Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.



Q: "I also need to save time to increase performance of this playbook, as sometime this looping body might be a huge array and we don't need to check the following items when some condition matched."
If you like or need to implement such behavior you may need to write something by yourself. See in example Should you develop a module? and Developing modules.
An other approach can be to do some pre-processing on the data structure, os_vars list to have after that only
os_vars:
  - 8
  - 10
  - 15
  - 6

to provide for the loop. Then, no break or if then else construct would be necessary at all.
Further Reading

What is the XY problem?
Ansible: Stop a loop when the conditional is true the first time and the threads like Looping a task until it succeeds, How to dynamically end a loop in Ansible, ...
Ansible Issue #51881 - "Add break_when to the loop_control"
Ansible Pull Request #62151 - "[WIP] loop_control until feature"


Based on the given comments and as I understood the Use Case a possible solution approach without BREAK, when: or any IF, THEN, ELSE construct.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    os_vars:
      - 8
      - 10
      - 15
      - 6
      - 0
      - 7
      - 25

  tasks:

  - name: Loop up to idx
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ os_vars[:idx | int] }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index }}"
    # Get index of zero (0) value
    vars:
      idx: "{{ os_vars.index(os_vars | min) }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [Loop up to idx] ********
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 8
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 10
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 15
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) =>
  msg: 6

Based On

How to get the index of a list value in Ansible?
Ansible - How to use a variable as a slice value?


Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. Now we can see -- someone like to add this feature from 2019 but still unavailable today... :(

Right. But I like to recommend again to overthink the Use Case. Maybe you can Remove items from the list before. In order to help with that we would need an other question with a more detailed description regarding your data structure and what you try achieve instead of focusing on a maybe solution.

Also, it should be possible to implement a Custom Filter based on How to remove an element from a list by index or just using Python Slice Notation for accessing the list elements. Find the index of 0 and loop only over the list up to that index.

Thanks again... Your comment is very instructive... I'll take a look an think about it ... :)

Please find a possible solution approach based on the given comments attached.

Thanks a lot.  With your sample code I rewrite my playbook with limited array like -- with_items: "{{ checkfile_lines[(table_head_index|int):(table_close_index|int)] }}".. And it works fine. The runtime dropped from 5m to 20 s.... thanks again.
